# I have two loss layers in my caffe model. When I set the loss_weight of one to zero, the entire model stops training. What's going on?

Tags: caffe

The Caffe documentation on [loss layers](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/loss.html) says that I can set the loss_weight parameter on any layer to 0. This would negate any contribution the layer would make to the loss function. However, when I put in two different loss layers and set the loss_weight of one of them to zero, the network stops training entirely, even though there are two loss layers to work with.

I illustrate with LeNet on the MNIST dataset. Two changes are made to the LeNet .prototxt:

1) A loss_weight parameter is added to the SoftmaxWithLoss layer, setting the loss weight to 0.5.
2) The changed SoftmaxWithLoss layer is duplicated, creating two of the same loss layers, both with loss weights with 0.5.

EDIT: Here is the Caffe output for two layers with loss_weights with 0.5:

```
I0729 01:06:58.008580  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.0024
I0729 01:06:58.008597  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 4.68486 (* 0.5 = 2.34243 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.008600  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #2: loss2 = 4.68486 (* 0.5 = 2.34243 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.011636  1336 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 0 (0 iter/s, 0.102775s/100 iters), loss = 4.72888
I0729 01:06:58.011657  1336 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 4.72888 (* 0.5 = 2.36444 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.011662  1336 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #1: loss2 = 4.72888 (* 0.5 = 2.36444 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.011669  1336 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 0.01
I0729 01:06:58.035707  1336 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 10, Testing net (#0)
I0729 01:06:58.035722  1336 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 01:06:58.035724  1336 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer label_data_1_split
I0729 01:06:58.128404  1343 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 01:06:58.131825  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.4744
I0729 01:06:58.131842  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 1.70187 (* 0.5 = 0.850937 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.131846  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #2: loss2 = 1.70187 (* 0.5 = 0.850937 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.155300  1336 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 20, Testing net (#0)
I0729 01:06:58.155344  1336 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 01:06:58.155352  1336 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer label_data_1_split
I0729 01:06:58.249866  1343 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 01:06:58.253347  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.5036
I0729 01:06:58.253365  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 1.47916 (* 0.5 = 0.739582 loss)
I0729 01:06:58.253368  1336 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #2: loss2 = 1.47916 (* 0.5 = 0.739582 loss)
```

Training proceeds completely normally, with the same performance as the unmodified .prototxt; the accuracy quickly rises to .90 within the first hundred or so iterations, then plateaus around .98 thereafter.

Then, when one of the loss_weights are set to 0 and the other is set to 1, the model stops training entirely, with accuracy at 0 and loss constant at 87.3365.

This is what the added layer looks like in the caffe .prototxt; everything else is the same as the base lenet .prototxt.

```
layer {
  name: "loss2"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip_s2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss2"
  loss_weight: 0
}
```

Here is the relevant caffe output:

```
I0729 00:45:06.989990  1318 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 0 (-0.00385461 iter/s, 0.0972042s/100 iters), loss = 4.75995
I0729 00:45:06.990005  1318 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 4.75995 (* 1 = 4.75995 loss)
I0729 00:45:06.990010  1318 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #1: loss2 = 4.75995
I0729 00:45:06.990020  1318 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 0.01
I0729 00:45:07.013304  1318 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 10, Testing net (#0)
I0729 00:45:07.013320  1318 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 00:45:07.013322  1318 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer label_data_1_split
I0729 00:45:07.071669  1318 blocking_queue.cpp:49] Waiting for data
I0729 00:45:07.107491  1325 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 00:45:07.112396  1318 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0
I0729 00:45:07.112416  1318 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 87.3365 (* 1 = 87.3365 loss)
I0729 00:45:07.112419  1318 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #2: loss2 = 87.3365
I0729 00:45:07.134907  1318 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 20, Testing net (#0)
I0729 00:45:07.134958  1318 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 00:45:07.134965  1318 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer label_data_1_split
I0729 00:45:07.223928  1325 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 00:45:07.226883  1318 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0
I0729 00:45:07.226912  1318 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 87.3365 (* 1 = 87.3365 loss)
I0729 00:45:07.226920  1318 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #2: loss2 = 87.3365
```

Compared with the caffe output of the unedited lenet prototxt:

```
I0729 00:51:35.134851  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.0287
I0729 00:51:35.134869  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 4.71456 (* 1 = 4.71456 loss)
I0729 00:51:35.137794  1327 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 0 (1.68966e+31 iter/s, 0.0944882s/100 iters), loss = 4.70328
I0729 00:51:35.137809  1327 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 4.70328 (* 1 = 4.70328 loss)
I0729 00:51:35.137821  1327 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 0.01
I0729 00:51:35.159623  1327 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 10, Testing net (#0)
I0729 00:51:35.159639  1327 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 00:51:35.249256  1334 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 00:51:35.252557  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.3437
I0729 00:51:35.252575  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 1.76758 (* 1 = 1.76758 loss)
I0729 00:51:35.275521  1327 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 20, Testing net (#0)
I0729 00:51:35.275537  1327 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 00:51:35.361196  1334 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 00:51:35.364228  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.7281
I0729 00:51:35.364244  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.926002 (* 1 = 0.926002 loss)
I0729 00:51:35.386831  1327 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 30, Testing net (#0)
I0729 00:51:35.386847  1327 net.cpp:676] Ignoring source layer data
I0729 00:51:35.468611  1334 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0729 00:51:35.471771  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.7942
I0729 00:51:35.471804  1327 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.654145 (* 1 = 0.654145 loss)
```

Is anyone able to duplicate the error or explain what is going on and how to fix this?

Thanks!